# How can i override WndProc method of C# in MONO

Tags: mono

I have just created "hello world!" in MONO. My next task is to convert my application created in .NET 3.5 to MONO. In my application I have override WndProc() method. My applications task is written in this method, so i can't remove it.
So, how can i override WndProc in MONO so that, it will work in MAC and Linux

Answer (score 0):

These days, [according to Mono's WinForms page](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/winforms/), one can override WndProc() normally and use it as if on Windows. Messages from other platforms are translated into Windows messages for compatibility.

Quote from the linked page:

> Mono’s Windows.Forms implementation translates the native system events such as X11 into Win32 WM_ messages and dispatches them using the WndProc mechanism. This allows applications that depend on overriding WndProc to get some features not exposed by the APIs to still run.